# How to change the value of an active text input using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onchange

I am trying to make a form with a date input.
However, this input is in date format, and I would like to change the value while the control is still active.
Here is the full code :

```js
 
// Javascript code

function add_value()
{
  var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("fin_mater").value;
  if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length = 2)
    {
      document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
    }
  else if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length = 5)
    {
      document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Code of the input -->

<input id="fin_mater" type="text" onchange="add_value();" name="fin_mater" maxlength="10" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
```

But this is only updating the text when you exit of the control, and I would like to know how to run this javascript function while the control is still active.

Thanks.

Comment: You have error in your code, you use = instead of == in if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's make the code smell more like the "javascript" :)

```js
 
// Javascript code
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

function add_value(event) {
    var dataOriginale = $("fin_mater").value, 
        len = dataOriginale.length,
        key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    // Allow BACKSPACE and DEL
    if (key === 8 || key === 46) {
        return true;
    }
    
    if(len === 2 || len === 5) {
        $("fin_mater").value = dataOriginale + '-';
    } 

    return false;
}
```

```html
<!-- Code of the input -->

<input id="fin_mater" type="text" onKeyUp="add_value(event);" name="fin_mater" maxlength="10" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
```

If you want to append the "-" automatically when you input numbers, you can listen on the "onKeyUp" event of the text box rather than the "onchange".

PS: You can use the key code to limit only numbers input and also do some validations.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onkeyup`.

```
<input id="fin_mater" type="text" onkeyup="add_value();" name="fin_mater" maxlength="10" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY"/>
```

From the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp)

> Execute a JavaScript when a user releases a key

Also in your `if` your are using `=`, you should be using `==`

```
...
if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 2)//==
...
else if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 5)
...
```

Comment: @Tripesdeporc. Didnt get you. You are adding `-` right? Y do you want to delete it?

Comment: If the user that will be writing this date mades a mistake, he has to be able to modify it.

Comment: @Tripesdeporc why don't you simply use `type="date"` instead of `type="text"`?

Comment: I tried to use the date input type but it doesn't change things, the problem is still there.

Comment: @Tripesdeporc I meant if you use `date` then you don't have to write any code as the browser will handle it. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xy95n4h/)

Comment: Firefox is not handling it. Internet Explorer handles this but not Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keypress():

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $( "#fin_mater" ).keypress(function() {
  var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("fin_mater").value;
  if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 2)
    {
      document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
    }
  else if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 5)
    {
      document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
    }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/32xcz948/)

Comment: Same thing, if the user wants to modify his input, he can't delete the 5 first characters... Do you know how to fix it ? Edit : Is this because the browser doesn't count the adding of the ' - ' in the value.length property ?

Answer (score 0):

With some of your help and some documentation, I finally went to this, that works perfectly on every browser that supports javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(event)
    {
    $( "#fin_mater" ).keypress(function(event) {
 var dataoriginale = document.getElementById("fin_mater").value;
 if(event.keyCode != 8)
 {
  if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 2)
   {
   document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
   }
  else if(document.getElementById("fin_mater").value.length == 5)
   {
   document.getElementById("fin_mater").value=dataoriginale+'-';
   }
 }
    });
});
```

Thanks everyone !